# CMake Install/CPack Problems: Improper Permissions AND Wrong Executables

Tags: c++, cmake, rpm, openmpi

I'm currently working on a project that is being built using CMake; it is then subsequently packaged up with CPack into an RPM.

The following is packaged into the RPM:

1. Several Executables
2. Configuration files

Some more context:

1. This project is running using OpenMPI, and there are X amount of nodes, depending on user input AND based on the # of nodes the user specifies, X docker containers are spawned.
2. There are instances of each executable running in tandem on each container
3. There is an OpenMPI crash and it is difficult to debug without GDB
4. The executables have been compiled as **Release**. However, if I want to make debugging possible I have been compiling the CMake project as **Debug**.
5. The executables are created as Debug. I have the **VERBOSE=1** flag on when making the package and can confirm that **-g** flag is present, and the executables have debug symbols when loading them into GDB locally

Some lines in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Bunch of compilation lines above
install(TARGETS executable_1 executable_2 executable_3 DESTINATION bin) # Installs the executables into a local bin dir
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr)

install(DIRECTORY bin/ DESTINATION /usr/bin)
install(DIRECTORY config/ DESTINATION /etc/PROJECT_NAME FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*")

# Making of the package
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "PROJECT_NAME")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION 0.1)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE 1)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "ME")
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE}.${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_AUTOREQ 0)
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELOCATABLE True)
include(CPack)
```

The problem:

1. When CPack is doing its thing and creating the RPM, the executables can be packaged into the RPM, but the problem is they have improper permissions; aka when the executables are installed on the Containers, they cannot be executed. I can address this by adding:

   ```
   # Bunch of compilation lines above
   install(TARGETS executable_1 executable_2 executable_3 DESTINATION bin) # Installs the executables into a local bin dir
   set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
   set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr)

   # Permissions Fix
   set(PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_DEFAULT
       OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE
       GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE
       WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE)
   install(DIRECTORY bin/ PERMISSIONS ${PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_DEFAULT} DESTINATION /usr/bin)
   install(DIRECTORY config/ DESTINATION /etc/PROJECT_NAME FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*")

   # Making of the package
   set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "PROJECT_NAME")
   set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION 0.1)
   set(CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE 1)
   set(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
   set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "ME")
   set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

   set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE}.${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
   set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_AUTOREQ 0)
   set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELOCATABLE True)
   include(CPack)
   ```
2. After adding the permissions, the permission are fixed, but for some reason the executables that are copied do not have debug symbols anymore; my local executables in the **bin/** folder are the proper executables which have symbols, but the executables packaged into the RPM DOT NOT have debug symbols. Meaning somewhere along the way, something really odd is happening.

My question is, why? Either way results in a different problem. I'm wondering if there is a way to make sure the permissions are correct AND the proper executables get copied and packaged into the RPM. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use absolute install destinations and do not read `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, if you can avoid it. Using absolute install destinations (possibly indirectly through the use of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`) forces you to run the `install` target with privileges that allow the process to modify those absolute paths. This usually means you have to use `sudo` to run the install target, even when installing to a directory owned by the standard user.

Since running `cpack` involves running the install target with the install prefix replaced with a directory inside the build directory (basically `cmake --install ... --prefix ...`), you can avoid the need for root privileges, if you use relative install locations.

My preferred the install logic here would be:

```
# allow the installation into any directory below the file system root
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /)

# set the default executable install location, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-targets
# Note: could be set "globally", i.e. from the toplevel CMakeLists.txt allowing installation of individual targets
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR usr/bin)

install(TARGETS executable_1 executable_2 executable_3 RUNTIME)

#preferrably replace this with install(FILES ... TYPE BIN) to install individual files
set(PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_DEFAULT
    OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ OWNER_EXECUTE
    GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE
    WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE)
install(DIRECTORY bin/ PERMISSIONS ${PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_DEFAULT} DESTINATION usr/bin)

# preferrably replace this with install(FILES ... TYPE SYSCONFIG)
install(DIRECTORY config/ DESTINATION etc/PROJECT_NAME FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*")

# Making of the package
...
```

I assume in your scenario somewhere along the way you got the file permissions incorrect the cmake build / install / package process.

Comment: Fabian, thank you very much for your answer. I actually fixed up my build file with your suggestions. I also moved away from using sudo when building the project, so thank you for that.

However, when adding in the `PERMISSIONS ${PROGRAM_PERMISSIONS_DEFAULT}` flag to the install line, the permissions are fixed, but the executables do not have debug symbols. The reverse is also true. Without the PERMISSONS flag, the permissions of the executables are not correct, BUT the executables do have debug symbols..... I genuinely do not understand why.